# how to make a node stack on top of another node and follow the object?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to create a game in which i have a object 1 rotatiing in a circle and another object appears and places itself ontop of object 1. currently the object just rotates around object 1 without stacking ontop of it. how do i get the object to stack itself on top and then follow it's orbit? here's my code now.

```
let player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Light")

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    // 2
    backgroundColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
    // 3
    player.position = CGPoint(x: size.width * 0.5, y: size.height * 0.5)
    // 4
    player.size = CGSize(width:70, height:60 )
    addChild(player)

    let dx = player.position.x - self.frame.width / 2
    let dy = player.position.y - self.frame.height / 2

    let rad = atan2(dy, dx)

    circle = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: size.width / 2, y: size.height / 2), radius: 120, startAngle: rad, endAngle: rad + CGFloat(M_PI * 4), clockwise: true)
    let follow = SKAction.followPath(circle.CGPath, asOffset: false, orientToPath: true, speed: 100)
    player.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(follow))
}    
func addMonster() {
    let monster = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "plate")

    // Determine where to spawn the monster along the Y axis
    let actualY = random(min: monster.size.height/1, max: size.height - monster.size.height/1)

    // Position the monster slightly off-screen along the right edge,
    // and along a random position along the Y axis as calculated above
    monster.position = CGPoint(x: size.width * 0.5 + monster.size.width/2, y: actualY)

    // Add the monster to the scene
    addChild(monster)

    // Determine speed of the monster
    let actualDuration = random(min: CGFloat(2.0), max: CGFloat(3.0))

    // Create the actions
    let actionMove = SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x: -monster.size.width/2, y: actualY), duration: NSTimeInterval(actualDuration))

    let follow = SKAction.followPath(circle.CGPath, asOffset: false, orientToPath:true, speed: 100)
    monster.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(follow))
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [SKConstraint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKConstraint_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/SKConstraint).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your verbal description appears to have something like the following in mind (you can copy and paste this into an iOS playground):

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import XCPlayground

let scene = SKScene(size: CGSize(width: 400, height: 400))
let view = SKView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: scene.size))
view.presentScene(scene)
XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.liveView = view

scene.backgroundColor = .darkGrayColor()
scene.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)

let player = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: CGSize(width: 70, height: 60), cornerRadius: 5)

let radius: CGFloat = 120
let circle = CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(CGRect(x: -radius, y: -radius, width: radius * 2, height: radius * 2), nil)

let followCircle = SKAction.followPath(circle, asOffset: false, orientToPath: true, speed: 100)
player.runAction(.repeatActionForever(followCircle))

let monsterSize = CGSize(width: 35, height: 30)
let monster = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: monsterSize, cornerRadius: 4)
monster.fillColor = .redColor()

monster.runAction(.repeatActionForever(followCircle))

scene.addChild(player)
scene.addChild(monster)
```

Where you make use of a `random(min:max:)` function that is probably implemented along the lines of:

```
public func random(min min: CGFloat, max: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    return min + (CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UInt32.max)) * (max - min)
}
```

But you also have the code that seems to be saying:

```
let y = random(
    min: scene.size.height / -2 + monsterSize.height / 2,
    max: scene.size.height / 2 - monsterSize.height / 2
)
let xFrom = scene.size.width / 2
let xTo = scene.size.width / -2
monster.position = CGPoint(x: xFrom, y: y)
monster.runAction(
    .moveToX(xTo, duration: NSTimeInterval(random(min: 2, max: 3)))
)
```

But this is unused. Instead the monster is set to follow the same circle path as the player. And so I am not sure really what exactly you are trying to achieve. (By the way, the simplest way of getting the monster "stack on top" of the player would be to make it the child node of the player...)

Hope some of this guesswork helps you in some way (to refine your question and code sample if nothing else).